# why wifi password changed showed in windows network property

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I need to tell other's my wifi password. However I forget it so I just look up the network wifi property. Encrypted in WEP.
But it is not the original password. It become quite long!
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've recovered is the true, 10 or 26 hexadecimal WEP key.  When you created the key, you probably used a pass-phrase to generate the key; you can use either to validate yourself to the network, although the router itself only verifies the 10/26 hexadecimal digits.

Also, at the time of writing this, [WEP has been shown to be insecure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Flaws).  You should transition to WPA-2 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your router via web browser. From there it can tell you what your password is. If you have troubles trying to connect to your router, Google: the brand and how to login. Some routers use an IP address, others use domain names. It also helps to know your login credentials for the router, usually it's the factory default or printed on a sticker on the router itself.

> EX: Netgear routers can be accessed by typing in `routerlogin.net`